# Image Preview is not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn React Native. I am currently learning react native navigation.
While passing parameters on via react native navigation image is not working.

In web version Image preview is working fine.
I tried to passing height and width also in image props but still not working.

i have not tried with local image.

I am using network image which is not working

Please help me to solve this problem.

App .js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Card from "./Card";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello HomeScreen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Mobile Phone"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "One Plus 7",
              image: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                uri:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1092644/pexels-photo-1092644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 1000",
            });
          }}
        />
        <Button
          title="Laptop"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "MackBook",
              image: {
                uri:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/5614263/pexels-photo-5614263.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 99999",
            });
          }}
        />

        <Button
          title="Fridge"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "Fridge",
              image: {
                uri:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2962002/pexels-photo-2962002.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 9999",
            });
          }}
        />

        <Button
          title="Book"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "Book",
              image: {
                uri:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/256450/pexels-photo-256450.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 99",
            });
          }}
        />
        <Button
          title="Mouse"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "Mouse",
              image: {
                uri:
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527864550417-7fd91fc51a46?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bW91c2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 9999",
            });
          }}
        />
        <Button
          title="Charger"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              title: "Charger",
              image: {
                uri:
                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583863788434-e58a36330cf0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8Y2hhcmdlcnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
              },
              subTitle: "Price : 9999",
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card
          title={this.props.route.params.title}
          image={this.props.route.params.image}
          subTitle={this.props.route.params.subTitle}
        />

        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          <Button
            title="Go to Home"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop("Home")}
          />

          <Button
            title="Go to Back"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          />

          <Button
            title="cHECK sTACK"
            onPress={() => console.log(this.props.navigation)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    padding: 10,
  },
  image: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

Card.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

// import colors from "../config/colors";
import AppText from "./AppText";

function Card({ title, subTitle, image }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Image style = {styles.image} source={image} />
      <View style = {styles.detailsContainer}>
        <AppText style = {styles.title} >{title}</AppText>
        <AppText style = {styles.subTitle} >{subTitle}</AppText>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    marginBottom: 20,
    overflow : 'hidden'
  },
  detailsContainer : {
    padding : 20,

  },
  image :{
      width : '100%',
      height : 200,
      backgroundColor :'grey'
  },
  subTitle :{
      color : "green",
      fontWeight : 'bold',

  },
  title : {
    marginBottom : 7,

  }
});
export default Card;
```

**Mobile Screenshot**

[image]

**Web screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `width`

Needed a `fixed` width instead of `percentage`

Comment: Its not working :(
can you also see the passing parameters because i am passing image as a object

Comment: Oh I see that you are passing the image prop correctly so you wrote it right previously...Try changing the styles...width from 100% to a fixed height lets say 200

Comment: thanks bro itw working after changing width. The problem was in width. Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Also I would suggest you to remove that `wdith:300, height: 300` from the onPress prop of the button whose `title` is `"Mobile Phone"`.. Check you have provided the `uri`, as well as `wdith:300, height: 300`

Comment: I have removed. I was just checking by giving additional props. You can see in rest of the button components i have not given that